# WSO2ESB. issue with java_home

Tags: java, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu server, with PostgresSQL installed on it, as well as Apache Ant and Maven.

I configured the `JAVA_HOME` but but when I try to start the server I am getting an error that it is not defined correctly:

> Carbon cannot execute /usr/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_121/bin/bin/java.

But I defined the `JAVA_HOME` correctly. When I execute the command `echo $JAVA_HOME` I get `/usr/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_121/bin/bin/java`. But in `JAVA_HOME` I defined the path in the `.bashrc` as `/usr/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_121`.

When I execute the command `whereis java` I get the path `/usr/bin/java`.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Issue the following;

```
export $PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```